# Does God not like to be flattered?

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, shemot-exodus

I heard from a Hasidic rabbi that God doesn't like people who flatter him, even literally in those terms. He cites the episode of Moses that confronts God's position of putting an end to the people with their murmurings and blasphemies in the desert and making a new people from Moses, in which Moses then asks that he erase him from the book of life because that would be a affronts the promise he made to Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob. Does this reflect the thinking of this rabbi? Or did he overdo it in that position? Does the case of Abraham bargaining with God instead of coldly accepting the decision to destroy Sodom and Gomorrah also go this way? He says that Noah had a cold understanding of God, accepting the reality of the flood without contesting or bargaining with God for that generation, saying that Noah was a righteous person different from a righteous one of the Jewish people because they contest God and Noah did not contest. Does this have corroboration in the Jewish bosom? Does God sometimes test a person with extreme actions expecting him to behave in a different way to expose the person's true excellence? In the case of Moses, this rabbi said that Moses could agree with God, destroy these people, yes, be filled with pride and be the common progenitor of a new people, but he was not arrogant to that point, showing humility and mercy with those stiff-necked people.

Comment: "To flatter" means "to heap praise upon someone to further one's own interests."  The sources are clear that God wants praise.  It is also clear that we praise God in prayer.  Whether we do it out of love or to "further our interests" depends on the individual.  So what, exactly, is your question?

Comment: My question has to do with this rabbi's statement that God does not want flatterers, this for the lay public is absurd, what do you mean God does not want us to blindly follow what he says? Then these examples of Moses and Abraham in comparison with Noah appear and seem to allude to the thought of this rabbi.

Comment: Dr Mizrahi is on the right lines. You need to look up exactly what the Jewish definition of flattery is, it's not simple: https://www.sefaria.org/Orchot_Tzadikim.24.1?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en There are 9 categories of flattery, which are broken up into further categories, and in the case of God, it means offering insincere praises. Of course He would object strongly to that, especially because He is the God of Truth (Jeremiah 10:10), and can see one's intentions (Jeremiah 17:10)

Comment: I think what I wanted to know is whether God wants us to blindly obey his commands or intervene with arguments to change the order. In the case of Noah he obeyed without thinking, in the case of Abraham and Moses they argued with God and one of them managed to reverse the destruction.

Comment: Yes, so I think your question is not about flattery, perhaps sycophancy, consider editing it. @Thales Two points for you to consider. 1) Moshe was leader of the Jewish people. His role and duty was to put them before anything, argue for them and defend them, and put them before himself. Hashem credited Him for that. 2) Avraham in a similar theme asked for mercy. God wants us to make it our job to oppose and do all we can to alleviate all suffering, although of course not from the point of view that it is _unjust_. God is Just. Suffering is necessary, but we should never _like_ it, or settle.

Comment: @RabbiKaii Isn't being silent and blindly obeying without trying to persuade God to do something a kind of flattery?

Comment: @Thales no, that context would only be if the person being blindly obeyed was wicked.

Comment: I'll add my voices to those who are saying that "flattery" is not the word you want here.

Comment: So I think this rabbi mixed up the concepts or didn't know how to express himself correctly.

Comment: So flattery never applies to God since he is not wicked?

Comment: @Thales I have posted an answer that should give you all the information you need, hopefully

Comment: The description of your question is all over the place and makes it less clear what you are asking about

Comment: @Dude My question was based on what I learned from a local rabbi. If there's anything unclear, it must be with him and not with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of the 9 categories of flattery. None of them apply to God. You are perhaps wondering if category 6 applies to God, but certainly it does not. We do not view God as committing evil when He brings about suffering, we consider Him Just. The examples of biblical figures who "argued with God" are all presuming He is Just, and are seeing if they can argue for *Mercy*, because God expects us to abhor suffering, and do anything we can to alleviate it. He also abhors suffering (even though it is necessary) and makes us His partner in ending it for good.

Here are the 9 categories of flattery, as promised, summarised from [Orchot Tzaddikim 24](https://www.sefaria.org/Orchot_Tzadikim.24.1?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> Flattery may be divided into nine categories. The first is where a man
> knows that his friend is a wicked man and a deceiver,... yet this man
> who knows all this comes... saying "You did no wrong in what you did."
>
> The second category is where the flatterer praises a wicked man before
> people, whether in his presence or not, even though the flatterer does
> not justify him in his evil deeds but makes a general statement, "He
> is a good man."
>
> The third category is he who flatters a wicked man to his face (i.e.
> in private) and says to him, "What a charming and good man you are."
> ... And there is a type of flattery which one pays to the mighty, so
> that they will like them and raise them up and make them great.
>
> The fourth category of flattery is he who becomes a companion to the
> wicked. Even though he does not flatter him and does not praise him,
> but since he is near to him and in his company, he will be punished.
> Not only does he not rebuke him, but on the contrary, he brings him
> near to him in companionship, and puts him at a distance from his
> rebuke, and there is a sin in this.
>
> The fifth category is a man who is trustworthy in the eyes of all the
> people, and to whom everybody listens, and who appoints his relative
> as synagogue warden or as Rabbi, saying, "I have appointed him because
> he is wise," when the fact of the matter is not so, all the people
> rely upon him.
>
> The sixth category of flattery is he who is in a position to protest
> against an evil and does not protest, nor does he pay any attention to
> the deeds of the sinners. This thing comes close to flattery, for then
> the sinners think, "As long as they do not protest and do not reproach
> us, all of our deeds must be good."
>
> The seventh category of flattery is he who sees that the people of his
> place are very subborn and he says in his heart, "Perhaps they will
> not pay any attention if I rebuke them," and therefore, he refrains
> from reproving them. This, too, is a sin and he will bear his
> iniquity, for he did not attempt to warn and rebuke them; if he had
> done so, perhaps they would have repented.
>
> The eighth category is he who hears gossip or vile words, or who
> associates with scoffers and those who shame the Torah and the
> commandments, and he knows that they are stubborn and that they will
> not accept rebuke, and therefore is silent. He, too, will be punished,
> for it is up to him to answer them so they connot say that he is like
> them and that by his silence he admits the truth of their words.
>
> The ninth category of flattery is he who honors the wicked because he
> wants to preserve peace.

Certainly none of these types of flattery apply to God. If we generalise all of the above to "insincere praise", then certainly God does not approve of that either (who would?). He is the God of Truth (Jeremia 10:10) and He knows a person's hidden intentions (Jeremia 17:10)

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the question of if Hashem likes flattery, I can cite the medrash rabba berishes 32,3, that's says the following:

רבי אליעזר בנו של רבי יוסי הגלילי אמר מצינו שאומרים מקצת שבחו של מי שאמר והיה העולם בפניו וכו

Basically, even in regards to hashem, one should only say part of hashems praise.

Comment: There is no other option. How could one say all of God's praise?

Comment: The issue of flattery that this rabbi put on his live was that God does not like certain praise or agreement thinking of achieving selfish goals like Moses who could have remained silent and agreed with God in wanting to destroy the people and make a new one from Moses , Moses intervened for the people instead.

Comment: @DoubleAA it means, one should be careful to make sure we phrase our praises in such a way that they don't imply "and that's all I like about You", chas veshalom. Same with humans!